# Correct way of handling data with a service multi components / routes - Angular 2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I'm trying to wrap my head around the best way to handling data in a service to use in multi components / routes.

**Situation sketch**

I want to store information of the current logged in user and use it in multi places in my app. For example in a topbar component, on the profile page and profile edit page. Storing the information about the current user in a service is the way to go?

**Current setup**

I made a auth.service.ts file with al my methods. Here is the auth.service file.

```
export class AuthService {
  userProfile: FirebaseObjectObservable<UserProfile[]>;
  currentUserProfile: FirebaseObjectObservable<UserProfile[]>;

  constructor(private auth: FirebaseAuth, private router:Router, private af: AngularFire) { 
    this.getUserProfile().subscribe(data => {
        this.currentUserProfile = <FirebaseObjectObservable<UserProfile[]>>data;
      });
  }

  loginUser(email, password) {
   return this.auth.login({email,password});
  }

  createUser(email, password) {
    return this.auth.createUser({email,password});
  }

  getUser() {
    const user = new Subject();
    this.isAuthenticated().subscribe(
      authResp => {
        console.log('respons from getUser():', authResp.uid);
        user.next(authResp.uid);
        user.complete();
      },
      err => {
        user.error(err);
        user.complete();
      }
    )
    return user.asObservable();
  }

  createUserProfile(company:string, authData:any) {
    const key = authData.uid;
    this.userProfile = this.af.database.object('/users/' + key);

    const newUserProfile = {
        company: company,
        emailaddress: authData.auth.email
    }
    return this.userProfile.set(newUserProfile);
  }

  editUserProfile(currentData, newData) {
    return currentData.update(
      {
        company: newData.company
      }
    ).then( () =>
      this.router.navigate(['/profile'])
    );
  }

  getUserProfile() {
    const getUser = new Subject();
    this.getUser().subscribe(
        authResp => {
          console.log('response received from getUser():', authResp);
          const data = this.af.database.object(`users/${authResp}`);
          getUser.next(data);
          getUser.complete();
        },
        err => {
          getUser.error(err);
          getUser.complete();
        }
      )
     return getUser.asObservable();
   }

  resetPassowrd(email) {
    const authFb = firebase.auth();
    return authFb.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).then( function() {
      console.log('email send');
    } )
  }

  logout() {
    this.auth.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

  isAuthenticated(): Observable<any> {
    return this.auth;
  } 
}
```

Is it for example a good practice to populate the data for curruentUserProfile in the constructor of the service?

For my profile components I made the following route structure.

```
 { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, children: [
        { path: '', component: ProfileIndexComponent },
        { path: 'edit', component: ProfileEditComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]}
```

In the profileIndexComponent I want to show the user profile information. And in de profileEditComponent i want to edit the user profile information.

**Profile-index.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/index';
import { UserProfile } from '../userprofile';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-index',
  templateUrl: './profile-index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile-index.component.css']
})

export class ProfileIndexComponent implements OnInit {
  user: FirebaseObjectObservable<UserProfile[]>;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.authService.currentUserProfile;
  }
}
```

The template is bare bones:

```
<h2>Profile index component</h2>
{{ (user | async)?.company }}

<a [routerLink]="['/profile/edit']">Edit Profile</a>
```

**Edit Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { Validators, FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/index';
import { UserProfile } from '../userprofile';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-edit',
  templateUrl: './profile-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile-edit.component.css']
})
export class ProfileEditComponent implements OnInit {
  user: FirebaseObjectObservable<UserProfile[]>;
  form: FormGroup;
  error = false;
  errorMessage = '';

  constructor(private authService:AuthService, private fb:FormBuilder,  private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.user = this.authService.currentUserProfile;
      console.log('profile', this.authService.currentUserProfile)
      this.form = this.fb.group({
        company: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  onEdit() {
    this.authService.editUserProfile(this.user, this.form.value); 
  }
}
```

And the template with the form included

```
  <h2>Profile edit component</h2>
  <a [routerLink]="['/profile']">cancel</a>

  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onEdit()">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="company">Company</label>
          <input formControlName="company" type="company" id="company" #company class="form-control" value="{{ (user | async)?.company }}">
          <span *ngIf="!company.pristine && company.errors != null && company.errors['noCompany']">No Company name</span>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Change profile</button>
  </form>
```

The current solution is working sort of. But every time I visit the profile components the data is loading again. And when I refresh the browser on /profile the data is undefined. I have to navigate back to root url and then navigate back to the /profile page to retrieve the data again.

I hope you guys have suggestions to improve my newbie code. I need some help to get me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in the heading in the right direction. Here are just a few pointer.

- I would create a state service and use that to store the user information, not the auth service.
- I wouldn't load the user information in the constructor of the service as that will impact your ability to test the service. Just put it in an getUser() function and call that from within ngOnit on your component.
- If you refresh the page on the /profile route, the data will always be null as you have it now because you are not loading the user profile, and the Angular is acting like it's first loading the application. This is a common shortfall of client side applications. The way to resolve it to account for passing the user id as part of the profile route, checking if you have the cached data, and loading it from the back-end if you don't.